# Want to apply foreign key on tables

Tags: mysql, django

I have two tables show as follows. I want to use these tables in django.I want to apply foreign Key on these tables. But I'm confuesed. The data of `title column` and `title_id column` are same on both tables. Can anyone help me? thanks

First Table is >

[image]

Second table is
[image]

EDIT: Here is my django model class
http://dpaste.com/645222/

Comment: You could add foreign key (e.g. - second_table.id -> first_table.id) fields. But firstly, try to normalize tables; then add FK to make a reference between child and parent tables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the columns names simply. You can append the table names as a prefix in column names. For example say your first table is `table1` then your columns of your first table should be `table1_id`, `table1_title`,`table1_slug`,`table1_title_id`. Similarly for second table do the same....

Comment: What the benefit of doing this? Did you check my django class model?